# what are the args that are being passed from clang to llc?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llc

I am working on the llvm project. Recently I tryed to compiler one of my .c files using clang command line into an .s file by using the next command:

```
clang --target=arch -S -O0 select.c -o select.s
```

and it crashed in the backend in the function ARCHInstrInfo::storeRegToStackSlot with the backtrace of the stack.
However when I tryed to do it in steps:

```
clang  -O0 -emit-llvm select.c -c -o select.bc
llc  -filetype=asm -march=arch  ./select.bc -o ./select.s  -print-after-all -debug-only isel
```

it succeeded !! (?)
How can I see how the clang is calling to the backend (llc) ?
I tryed to run the clang with -v flag but it didn't printed how it is calling to the backend...

Comment: You can't see "how the clang is calling to the backend (llc)" because it is not.
llc is a command line tool that invoke the backend on some IR, but clang does not invoke, its driver will build the backend directly.

Answer (score 0):

So the first one that sticks out is that llc defaults to O2 rather than O0 so you might want to look there first.

Comment: I think it takes that opt level from the .bc file cause I can't pass -O0 to the llc...

Comment: Sure you can. Look at llc -help.